# allow for vs. note

Tags: verbs, phrasal-verbs

*Take account of* in [Collins American Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/take-account-of):

> ​1. **to take into consideration**; allow for
>
> ​2. **to take notice of**; note

Would you simply tell me what the difference is between 1 and 2?

Comment: Very little difference. "Take notice of" might have a bit more of a nuance about something tangible, like touch, taste, smell, sight, sound ("He took notice of the bear off to the right of the path".); while "take consideration of" might tend slightly towards the intangible ("The author considered the ideas of Ibn Sina [Avicenna] in formulating his reply.")

Comment: You will get a better picture by comparing usage examples. Try to Google the phrases.

Comment: @brasshat There *is* a very significant difference. And it's not much about tangibility.

Comment: The title and body do not seem to match.

Comment: 'Note' does not necessarily imply any change in one's course of action on becoming aware of the new data; 'allow for' certainly does.

Answer (score 2):

To "note" something is to recognize it.  To "allow for" is to tolerate or accommodate.

For instance, you agree to meet your wife for supper at a favorite restaurant at 8 PM. Later, you realize that it's Friday.  You *allow for* the heavy traffic by leaving the office 30 minutes early.  If you merely *note* that Friday traffic is a bear, you are going to have a seriously unhappy wife.

Comment: This is the answer. There *can* be a *big* difference between the two.